# How to sum up date and time?

Tags: mysql, date, time, sum, time-format

I tried summing up:

```
SUM(TIME_FORMAT(TIMEDIFF(eTime, sTime),'%d d %k h %i m')) AS the_Time FROM Business
```

However, if I remove SUM it displays the format I want. If I add SUM then it returns null. Can anyone tell me how to sum up date and time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to sum up and then format

```
TIME_FORMAT(SUM(TIMEDIFF(eTime, sTime),'%d d %k h %i m')) AS tTime FROM Business
```